# What does .transform('first') do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Somebody helped me for a code. I understood everything in the code except the very last row `.transform('first')` I see what it does (I can see it), but I'd like to precisely know what it's doing behind to obtain this result.

This is the part of the code I understand :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['YEP'] = ( df[::-1].loc[df['Type'].eq('Budget')]
                     .groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)
                     .Value
                     .cumsum()
                     .sub(df['Value'])
                     .add(df['YTD'])
)
```

This is the output of this first part :

```
    Value    Type       Date    YTD     YEP
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101.0   974.0
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199.0  1022.0
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275.0  1078.0
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332.0  1012.0
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01    NaN     NaN
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01    NaN     NaN
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01    NaN     NaN
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01    NaN     NaN
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01    NaN     NaN
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01    NaN     NaN
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01    NaN     NaN
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01    NaN     NaN
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101.0     NaN
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199.0     NaN
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275.0     NaN
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332.0     NaN
```

This is the entire code :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['YEP'] = ( df[::-1].loc[df['Type'].eq('Budget')]
                     .groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)
                     .Value
                     .cumsum()
                     .sub(df['Value'])
                     .add(df['YTD'])
                     .groupby(df['Date'])
                     .transform('first') )
```

I got this after running the entire code :

```
    Value    Type       Date    YTD     YEP
0     100  Budget 2019-01-01  101.0   974.0
1      50  Budget 2019-02-01  199.0  1022.0
2      20  Budget 2019-03-01  275.0  1078.0
3     123  Budget 2019-04-01  332.0  1012.0
4      56  Budget 2019-05-01    NaN     NaN
5      76  Budget 2019-06-01    NaN     NaN
6      98  Budget 2019-07-01    NaN     NaN
7     126  Budget 2019-08-01    NaN     NaN
8      90  Budget 2019-09-01    NaN     NaN
9      80  Budget 2019-10-01    NaN     NaN
10     67  Budget 2019-11-01    NaN     NaN
11     87  Budget 2019-12-01    NaN     NaN
12    101  Actual 2019-01-01  101.0   974.0
13     98  Actual 2019-02-01  199.0  1022.0
14     76  Actual 2019-03-01  275.0  1078.0
15     57  Actual 2019-04-01  332.0  1012.0
```

I know that "transform" is like "apply". But I don't get what it means to apply - or `transform` -with this parameter `first`. What does `first` do here combined with `transform` ?

Thank you

Comment: For each group you set the first item of the group (here grouped by date) to all items in that group.

Comment: also `transform` is there to allow you to run groupby operations without modifying the index.

Answer (score 9):

1. #### What does it mean 'first'?

The parameter in the `.transform()` method may be a NumPy function, a *string function name* or a user-defined function. It means that in the line

```
    .transform('first')
```

it's a *string function name*. So it represents *the function `first()`*.

---

2. #### Where is the function `first()` coming from?

It's a GroupBy's method [`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html).

---

3. #### What does the function `first()` return?

It returns the *first non-`NaN` value* in a series, or `NaN` if there is none.

---

4. #### What does the method `.transform()` do?

It applies its parameter-function *to every column (i.e. the series)* of dataframe to obtain a *new (transformed)* column. Then it returns a dataframe consisting of such (transformed) columns.

In the case of series it returns — of course — a transformed *series*.

---

5. #### It means that function-parameter of `.transform` method must return a series with the same size?

No, it is only one possibility.
The other is a *scalar* — it will be broadcasted (repeated) to make a series with the same size.

The used function (the GroupBy's method `first()`) is a good example of such a function.

---

6. #### So what does the method `.transform('first')` return?

It returns a series / dataframe with the same shape as the source group chunk, in which all values in every individual column are replaced with the *first non-`NaN` value* in this column, or with `NaN` if there is none.

---

#### Conclusion:

The lines

```
                 .groupby(df['Date'])
                 .transform('first')
```

first split your (intermediate) series into groups of *individual dates* and then — just before recombination — apply the `first()` function to every series in every group.

It effectively replaces every value in every group with the first non-`NaN` value in its series if such a value exists.

*This means that in the resulting series (your new column) will be all values of (intermediate) series replaced with the first non-`NaN` value in the same day (if such a value in the same day exists).*

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by dates (`groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)`), each value is changed to the value of the row where this date first appears. This changes the last value of the `'Actual'` rows to the original values from `'Budget'` rows.